# Joint and Marginal distributions of a random sample

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots ,X_{n}$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a population distribution $F$. I want to find the following:
1. the joint P.d.f of $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots ,X_{n}$.
2. the marginal probability distribution of $X_{j}$ for any $j$ in $1\leq j \leq n$.

---

This is my attempt for 1.
Given $F$, the joint pdf of the random sample is
$$\begin{align*}
F\left(X_{1},X_{2},\ldots ,X_{n}\right) & =P \left(X_{1}\leq x_1, X_{2}\leq x_2, \ldots X_n\leq x_n \right)\\
&=P(X_1 \leq x_1)P(X_2\leq x_2)\dot{} \ldots \dot{}P(X_n\leq x_n) \\
&=\left[P(X_1\leq x_1)\right ]^n \qquad \because X_j\text{'s are identical}
\end{align*} $$

---

Here are my questions: First, iIs my attempt for 1. right. Is there a better way of doing it.Second, I would like some help with 2. I know the $X_j$'s will all have the same marginal distributions, but I don't know how to justify it.

Thanks.

Comment: This PDF looks like the **cumulative** density function (CDF) for the random variable $\max \{ X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n \}$, rather than the joint PDF.  BTW by probability distribution, do you mean PDF or CDF?

Comment: Are you referring to the first or second question?

Comment: Actually, both. I am hoping the word "probability distribution" is used in a consistent sense in this question.

Comment: The last line (the one with "$\dots$ identical") is completely wrong.  If we have independent random sampling, say from a continuous distribution, the joint density is the product of the individual densities, which in this context are called marginal densities.  Keep the different variables $x_j$.

Comment: If $F(x)$ is the population cdf, and $f(x)$ is the population pdf, then the marginal pdf of $X_j$ is $f(x_j)$, by independence.

Comment: @Srivatsan: There's no such thing as a "cumulative density function".  The words "cumulative" and "density" contradict each other.

Comment: @Michael Yes, "cumulative density function" is wrong, thanks for pointing it out. (The funny thing is I pretty much always use CDF, but here I used the expanded form since I wanted to emphasize the word "cumulative". :)) But my doubt/confusion still remains, with "cumulative density function" replaced by "cumulative distribution function".

Answer (score 2):

We will assume that the $X_j$ are *independent*.  This assumption is not automatically built into the definition of random sampling, but it is necessary if we are to give a complete answer.

If $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function for the population, and $F_n(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n)$ is the joint sample (cumulative) distribution function, then, more or less as you wrote, we have
$$F_n(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=P(X_1 \le x_1)(P(X_2\le x_2)\cdots P(X_n \le x_n).$$
Please note that $F_n$ is a function of the $n$ real variables $x_1, x_2, \dots,x_n$. (No caps!)  The reasoning that you used to get to this stage was correct.

We can therefore write
$$F_n(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=F(x_1)F(x_2)\cdots F(x_n).$$

The final displayed expression in the post, namely $[P(X_1 \le x_1)]^n$, is not correct, and cannot be correct, for it does not mention the variables $x_2$ to $x_n$.  In the form $[F(x)]^n$, it does occur in the calculation of the distribution of the *largest* sample value, but that is not the problem  you were asked to look at.

If we want the joint *density* function $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, we just multiply the individual density functions $f(x_j)$.

The (marginal) distribution of any $X_j$ is, by independence, the same as the population distribution.  So if you want to specify the distribution by using a cdf, the answer would be simply $F(x_j)$.  If we are in a continuous situation, and $F'(x)=f(x)$, then the (marginal) density function of $X_j$ is $f(x_j)$.